# Dell Optiplex Micro 3060 WLAN slot to PCIe

Tags: networking, pci-express, m.2, dell-optiplex

I have an old Dell Optiplex Micro 3060 PC that I'd like to re-purpose as a Proxmox host. One of the VMs I would like to virtualize is pfSense, but I realise that I would need 2 NICs for it (Intel ones preferably). As far as I can see, the only available slot I can use is the WLAN M.2 2230 slot (E key I think), and I'm unsure what the maximum bandwidth of it is, although the Dell Support site simply states that it is `keyed to support Integrated or Discrete WiFi`.

[image]

Are there any recommendations for a 2230 adapter board that I can connect to this slot and lead to an PCIe adapter (maybe connected via ribbon cable)? I'd like to connect my old existing dual gigabit `Intel 82575 PCIe 1x Server LAN Card` to it, and pass that through to pfSense in Proxmox.

More importantly, is this feasible to do?

EDIT: would an A+E keyed card work here (I don't have any A+E cards to test the fit with)? I have been searching on AliExpress, but can't seem to see anything suitable.

PS: I'm aware that I will have a space constraint inside the case, but I'll make a plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the only available slot I can use is the WLAN M.2 2230 slot (E key I think), and I'm unsure what the maximum bandwidth of it is

E-key provides two PCIe lanes ("x2"; among other stuff such as USB pins for Bluetooth).

Given that it's commonly used for 802.11ac/ax interfaces (which might go well above 1 Gbps), it should be perfectly capable of supporting Gigabit Ethernet as well. My guess is that it'll be PCIe 2.0 or 3.0, supporting around ~10 Gbps or ~18 Gbps over the x2 link.

> More importantly, I this feasible to do?

PCIe is PCIe, as long as the firmware doesn't *deliberately* limit what could be inserted in that slot. (Some laptops, for example, reject even actual "unapproved model" Wi-Fi cards… and a Dell Micro is practically made out of laptop parts, so that's a possibility.)

I found quite a few "M.2 E-key to mini-PCIe" breakout cables for sale, so you could in theory go from M.2 → mini-PCIe → full-size PCIe, but it'll probably degrade the PCIe signal too much.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any that directly go to a full-size PCIe slot; all such products appear to be for B/M-keyed "SSD" slots only. Even Bplus, the usual source for cursed adapters, doesn't appear to have any for E-key.

As an alternative (if you really don't want Ethernet via USB3), it might be sufficient to just run two VLANs over the single built-in Ethernet interface (assuming you have a VLAN-capable switch to break out the ports). Ethernet is full-duplex and can support 1 Gbps up *and* 1 Gbps down over the same port simultaneously, so it's quite possible to have pfSense on a single port without losing much throughput.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Your last suggestion would not work in my case. I've heard horror stories about USB3-to-ethernet adapters, and I don't have a VLAN-capable switch. Your suggestion about "M.2 E-key to mini-PCIe" is definitely worth having a look at

Comment: In that case, obtaining a VLAN-capable switch would be easier than obtaining an adapter and getting it to work – I really don't trust those ribbon cables to carry PCIe. (Even if it's just a TL-SG108E, which only barely counts as a managed switch but still does 802.1Q VLANs, or nearly any Mikrotik desk router like hAP/hEX.)

Comment: hmmm ... that's a good point. Do you have any experience with this in regard to pfSense? I wonder if there are any potential bottlenecks with using pfSense through VLANs?

Comment: okay, I'm an absolute nutcase ... I actually do have an old Cisco SG200-08 smart switch that I have never used before. Just found it now while scrounging around in my hardware spares box.

Comment: If your big transfers mostly go in one direction at a time (e.g. copying files from subnet A → pfSense → subnet B), then VLANs will be fine. (Even though the traffic enters and exits the same Ethernet port, those are two independent 1G 'lanes' – entirely unlike Wi-Fi.) Only if you try to do a transfer in both directions simultaneously (one transfer A→B and another B→A), then they will compete and you'll be down to ~500 Mbps each, but that's generally not that common.

Comment: In general, while it's not ideal I believe it'll be at least _predictably_ reliable (and is a [very common configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_on_a_stick)), unlike stretching PCIe through two adapters and two long ribbon cables (which as I said I don't trust one bit) – things like Thunderbolt are explicitly designed with longer distances in mind, the internal slots are not. (If your micro PC had Thunderbolt, you could use that for external PCIe.)

Comment: I will try this suggestion using my Cisco switch and setting up VLANs. Thank you for your comprehensive feedback. I'll mark this as the answer and post back here if I have any further questions. I shouldn't, but you have pointed me in the right direction at least!